# How to avoid a flickering game display?

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason a weird squiggly wave keeps coming over my minecraft game. I cannot calculate the problem so I really need help because I have worked hard to come up with a game from scratch. If you see any problems to cause the strange wave please respond as soon as possible.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

BLACK = (0, 0, 0      )
BROWN = (153, 76, 0   )
GREEN = (0, 255, 0    )
BLUE  = (0, 0, 255    )
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

DIRT  = 0
GRASS = 1
WATER = 2
COAL  = 3

textures = {
                DIRT  : pygame.image.load("dirt.png"),
                GRASS : pygame.image.load("grass.png"),
                WATER : pygame.image.load("water.png"),
                COAL  : pygame.image.load("coal.png")
        }

inventory = {
               DIRT  : 0,
               GRASS : 0,
               WATER : 0,
               COAL  : 0
        }

TILESIZE  = 20
MAPWIDTH  = 30
MAPHEIGHT = 20

PLAYER = pygame.image.load("player.png")
playerPos = [0, 0]

resources = [DIRT,GRASS,WATER,COAL]
tilemap = [ [DIRT for w in range(MAPWIDTH)] for h in range(MAPHEIGHT) ]

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((MAPWIDTH*TILESIZE, MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE + 50))

INVFONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 18)

for rw in range(MAPHEIGHT):
    for cl in range(MAPWIDTH):
        randomNumber = random.randint(0, 15)
        if randomNumber == 0:
            tile = COAL
        elif randomNumber == 1 or randomNumber == 2:
            tile = WATER
        elif randomNumber >3 and randomNumber <= 7:
            tile = GRASS
        else:
            tile = DIRT
        tilemap[rw][cl] = tile

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT and playerPos[0] < MAPWIDTH - 1:
                playerPos[0] += 1
            if event.key == K_LEFT and playerPos[0] > 0:
                playerPos[0] -= 1
            if event.key == K_UP and playerPos[1] > 0:
                playerPos[1] -= 1
            if event.key == K_DOWN and playerPos[1] < MAPHEIGHT -1:
                playerPos[1] += 1
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                inventory[currentTile] += 1
                tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = DIRT
            if (event.key == K_1):
                currentTile = tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]]
                if inventory[DIRT] > 0:
                    inventory[DIRT] -= 1
                    tilemap[playerPos[1]][playerPos[0]] = DIRT
                    inventory[currentTile] += 1

    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]], (column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))

        DISPLAYSURF.blit(PLAYER,(playerPos[0]*TILESIZE,playerPos[1]*TILESIZE))

        placePosition = 10
        for item in resources:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[item],(placePosition,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+20))
            placePosition += 30
            textObj = INVFONT.render(str(inventory[item]), True, WHITE, BLACK)
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textObj,(placePosition,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+20))
            placePosition += 50

        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **you call** Pygames **`pygame.display.update()`** function **each iteration** in your `MAPHEIGHT` loop. Try to call `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` afterwards:

```
#import and game set up
...

#main game loop
while True:
    #event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    ...

    for row in range(MAPHEIGHT):
        for column in range(MAPWIDTH):
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[tilemap[row][column]], (column*TILESIZE,row*TILESIZE))

        DISPLAYSURF.blit(PLAYER,(playerPos[0]*TILESIZE,playerPos[1]*TILESIZE))

        placePosition = 10
        for item in resources:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textures[item],(placePosition,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+20))
            placePosition += 30
            textObj = INVFONT.render(str(inventory[item]), True, WHITE, BLACK)
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(textObj,(placePosition,MAPHEIGHT*TILESIZE+20))
            placePosition += 50

    #update (draw) the screen
    pygame.display.update()
```

Hope this helps :)